# Let : $A=\frac{2^{4n+2}+1}{5}$ , $n>1$

Tags: calculus, number-theory, prime-numbers, natural-numbers

Prove that the number A is not primary

Such that :

$A=\frac{2^{4n+2}+1}{5}$

$n≥2$

n=2 then $A=205$

Please I need some ideas to approach it

Comment: That is, $A$ is not prime.  Render $2^{4n+2}=4^{2n+1}$ and consider the factorization of $a^m+b^m$ for $m$ odd.

Answer (score 1):

The somewhat well-known identity
$4n^4+1
=(2 n^2 - 2 n + 1) (2 n^2 + 2 n + 1)
$
gives

$\begin{array}\\
2^{4n+2}+1
&=4(2^n)^4+1\\
&=(2\cdot 2^{2n}-2\cdot 2^n+1)(2\cdot 2^{2n}+2\cdot 2^n+1)\\
&=(2^{2n+1}-2^{n+1}+1)(2^{2n+1}+2^{n+1}+1)\\
\end{array}
$

and both factors are
greater than 5 for
$n \ge 2$.

Answer (score 0):

First,  the numerator is divisible by $5$.  This follows since $4^{2n+1}+1=(4+1)(4^{2n}-4^{2n-1}+\dots-4+1)$.

Second,  @marty cohen has shown that the numerator is the product of factors each greater than five.

It follows that $A\in\Bbb N$ is not prime.